# How to parse YouTube returned date to timestamp?

Tags: php, datetime, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

YouTube returns the `Updated date` and `Submitted on` date as follows: `2010-08-22T04:46:18.000Z`

Is there a PHP function, or a date mask that parses this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP", "2010-08-22T04:46:18.000Z");
var_dump($dt);
// object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
//   ["date"]=>
//   string(26) "2010-08-22 04:46:18.000000"
//   ["timezone_type"]=>
//   int(2)
//   ["timezone"]=>
//   string(1) "Z"
// }
```

This uses the [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class. It is timezone and fractional seconds aware. To display the date use the [`format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method:

```
echo $dt->format("Y-m-d H:i:s e");
// 2010-08-22 04:46:18 Z
```

To convert the date to local timezone use the [`setTimezone`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php) method:

```
$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get()));
echo $dt->format("Y-m-d H:i:s e");
// 2010-08-21 21:46:18 America/Los_Angeles
```

Answer (score 3):

sounds like [strtotime](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) is what you're looking for.

**EDIT:** if this doesn't work, take a look at the [Date and Time classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) - there are methods for parsing dates in specified formats ([like this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php) - doesn't return a timestamp directly, but if you construct a DateTime from this, you can use it's [getTimestamp](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php)-method)

Comment: strtotime doesn't return the correct timestamp for this date format!

Comment: strtotime should be able to parse this date. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php, section Localized Notations > SOAP

Comment: @doublethink `strtotime("2010-08-22T04:46:18.000Z")` → `1282452378`, `$ date -r 1282452378` → `2010年 8月22日 日曜日 13時46分18秒 JST` Looks pretty good to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$date=substr("2010-08-22T04:46:18.000z",0,strlen("2010-08-22T04:46:18.000z")-1);
$stamp=strtotime($date);
```

The "z" at the end seems to be the problem for strtotime.

Comment: Do you mean `substr("2010-08-22T04:46:18.000Z", 0, -1)` (which, BTW, is unnecessary)?

Comment: But `2010-08-22 04:46:18` is only the same date as `2010-08-22T04:46:18.000Z` if you're living in the UK. :)

Comment: Yup, if you think about it, it's relative at the time zone you were when the movie was added/edited :))